# Show/hide subpanels dynamically in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have created a view (a panel) with 3 subpanels ...
When the view loads , I want a function to run in viewController and based on its outcome , I want subpanel 1 to be visible(subpanel2 to be invisible) or subpanel2 to be visible(subpanel1 to be invisible)

How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for card layout. It is already implemented. So you don't have to implement again. Just tell it witch panel gonna be active it will do all layout things itself. Checkout this [api doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Card).

Comment: I created a card layout and called the viewController function in beforerender event to decide which panel should be made active

Comment: If it helped you, please accept as an answer for further refarance.

Answer (score 0):

May be the [`Accordion`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Accordion) layout can help you:

> This is a layout that manages multiple Panels in an expandable accordion style such that by default only one Panel can be expanded at any given time

Answer (score 0):

Give itemId to all three panel and then fireEvent.
Listener of view

```
listeners:{
    show: function(){
        me.fireEvent('showHidePanel');
    }
}
```

define showHidePanel method in Controller and in that method get panel by using `down()` with item id and hide/show panel by using `hide()`/`show()` method.

Comment: Dunno why this was voted down at one point. The solution here is valid - the Card layout is good as well, but if you need more control, you can explicitly hide and show the sub panels.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full example, it's quite straight forward:

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12kt)

```
Ext.define('FooController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.foo',

    init: function(view) {
        var child = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'p1' : 'p2';
        view.setActiveItem(this.lookupReference(child));
    }
})

Ext.define('Foo', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    layout: 'card',
    controller: 'foo',

    items: [{
        title: 'P1',
        reference: 'p1'
    }, {
        title: 'P2',
        reference: 'p2'
    }]
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    new Foo({
        renderTo: document.body,
        width: 200,
        height: 200
    });
});
```